# php sending email using gmail on several computer

Tags: php, email, ubuntu, smtp, gmail

I'm using a php application on different computers located on multiple site (not the same network = different IP address) and I get an error in my mail.err file:

```
Authorization failed (534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 n31sm9662128qte.40 - gsmtp)
```

Until I log into the gmail account and I authorize with the code sent to me. The account is correctly configured. The 2 ways validation is disabled and the parameter "allow less secure application" is activated.

Here's the code I use :

```
$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
//Additional headers
$headers .= "From: custom_email@gmail.com" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply: custom_email@gmail.com" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain" . PHP_EOL;

try {
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        echo 1;
    }
    else{
        echo 2;
    }
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Also, here's the `smtp.conf` file

```
root=custom_email@gmail.com           
UseSTARTTLS=YES
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587            
AuthUser=custom_email@gmail.com           
AuthPass=customPwd                  

rewriteDomain=gmail.com                                 
FromLineOverride=YES                    
hostname=localhost
```

and the `revaliases.conf`

```
root:custom_email@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
```

I have to access the gmail account from each client installed post ... which becomes impossible since we are not always on site when the computer is installed and we do not want to give access to our gmail account to our Customers ... Is this a good way to go? Is there a better solution? What are we doing wrong?

Please note that this computer is a small LAMP server installed on an xUbuntu with minimal installation. So we have no email account at the customer, the reason we use gmail.

Comment: I didn't use gmail like above but when I use gmail smtp via PHPMailer, there are 3 step for gmail account.

1. Allow suspicious activity.
https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity?hl=en&pli=1

2. Allow less secure app
https://www.google.com/settings/u/1/security/lesssecureapps

3. Allow new device login
https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

You said 2nd step completed. I recommend trying the rest 2.

Comment: It seems to work with the step 3. We are currently doing some tests!! We cross our fingers and toes...